# Python Fabric capture interactive dialog output

Tags: python, fabric

I would like to use Fabric to set the password for a user on a remote server.

Let's say I have a user named 'john' and I want to set a default password '123' for him.

Ideally I would like to do this:

```
run 'passwd john' on remote machine
detect when linux prompts for 'Enter new UNIX password:'
automatically enters the password
detect when linux prompts for 'Retype new UNIX password:'
automatically reenters the password
```

This is what I have tried:

```
result = run('passwd {}'.format(username))
```

The problem with this statement is that 'result' does not capture when Linux prompts for entering password. It only returns after the passwords are entered.

Is there a way to automate interactive prompts like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [prompts](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.10/usage/env.html#prompts)

```
password = '123'
with settings(prompts={
                  'Enter new UNIX password: ': password,
                  'Retype new UNIX password: ': password
              }):
    run('passwd {}'.format(username))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fexpect` for interactive prompts.